# Module 'cloud_firestore' not found flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I have created a small app but i am unable to run the app in ios simulator.
I have rerun pod install command many time.
i have tried to remove **Podfile** and **Podfile.lock** etc. I also tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` and then installed pod but nothing is working i am still unable to run the app.
I am using platform :ios, '11.0' in Podfile at the moment.

Comment: Have you run ```flutter doctor```?

Comment: yes and it shows "• No issues found!"

Comment: Add us please what is your ```flutter run --verbose``` returning

Comment: #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:289:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:590:11)
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:515:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
....